# How can I remove system of equations have no solution in this list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I select pair of tangents and find point of intersection of  them.

```
pC = {1, 3};
r = 5;
pM = {x, y};
pA = pM /. 
   Solve[{(x - pC[[1]])^2 + (y - pC[[2]])^2 == r^2}, {x, y}, Integers];
list = Table[
   ExpandAll[(pA[[i]] - pC) . (pM - pA[[i]])] == 0, {i, 1, 
    Length[pA]}];
ss = Subsets[list, {2}];
Table[{ss[[i]], {x, y} /. Solve[ss[[i]], {x, y}, Reals]}, {i, 1, 
  Length[ss]}]
```

[image]

Some of them have no intersection. How can I remove them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without changing your code too much:

```
Table[{ss[[i]], {x, y} /. Solve[ss[[i]], {x, y}, Reals]}, {i, 1, 
   Length[ss]}] // DeleteCases[#, {a__, {x, y}}] &
```

Answer (score 6):

The equation pair solutions are parallel tangents (diametrically opposed integer solutions). Just to visualize:

```
pts = {x, y} /. 
   Solve[({x, y} - {1, 3}) . ({x, y} - {1, 3}) == 25, {x, y}, 
    Integers];
crit = Norm[Cross[##]] & @@@ 
   Subsets[Append[#, 0] - {1, 3, 0} & /@ pts, {2}];
sub = Pick[Subsets[pts, {2}], crit, _?(# != 0 &)];
f[u_] := ({x, y} - u) . (u - {1, 3}) == 0;
eqn = Map[f, sub, {2}];
int = Join @@ ({x, y} /. Solve[#, {x, y}] & /@ eqn);
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[eqn]], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
 Epilog -> {Circle[{1, 3}, 5], Point[pts], Red, Point[int]}]
```

[image]

To cover the all points of tangent intersections:

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[eqn]], {x, -30, 30}, {y, -30, 30}, 
 Epilog -> {Circle[{1, 3}, 5], Point[pts], Red, Point[int]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
solutions = 
  Table[{ss[[i]], {x, y} /. Solve[ss[[i]], {x, y}, Reals]}, {i, 1, Length[ss]}];

valid = Cases[{_, {{__?NumberQ}}}] @ solutions;
```

No intersections

```
Complement[solutions, valid]
```

{{{-20 - 5 x == 0, -30 + 5 x == 0}, {x,
y}}, {{-10 - 5 y == 0, -40 + 5 y == 0}, {x,
y}}, {{-10 - 3 x - 4 y == 0, -40 + 3 x + 4 y == 0}, {x,
y}}, {{-12 - 4 x - 3 y == 0, -38 + 4 x + 3 y == 0}, {x,
y}}, {{-30 - 4 x + 3 y == 0, -20 + 4 x - 3 y == 0}, {x,
y}}, {{-34 - 3 x + 4 y == 0, -16 + 3 x - 4 y == 0}, {x, y}}}

Another possibility

```
pos = Position[sol, {_, {x, y}}]
```

{{11}, {20}, {28}, {35}, {41}, {46}}

```
Delete[pos] @ solutions;
```